# Suppose we have two algebraic closures of a field $F$. Show that there is an $F$-isomorphism between the two algebraic closures.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I came across the following question today which had myself and another saying "well, duh", and then we couldn't figure out how to prove it (oh, what fun).  So, here it is:

Suppose we have two algebraic closures of a field $F$.  Show that there is an $F$-isomorphism between the two algebraic closures.

We've tried more things than I'd like to admit to, but nothing has panned out, because we've been able to sort of, "trivially", rule out each direction we've gone.  We're both convinced that the idea can't be too deep, but it certainly eludes us both.

I did see this question on MSE: [If $F$ is a field, then any two algebraic closures are isomorphic by an isomorphism that is the identity on $F$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365802/if-f-is-a-field-then-any-two-algebraic-closures-are-isomorphic-by-an-isomorph) but I didn't want all of the assumptions. Just a more general thing.  Anyway, any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain how what you're asking is different from the question you linked to?  In order to prove what you want, you will need to use some kind of Zorn's lemma/axiom of choice argument.

Comment: Didn't want which "all of the assumptions", what is the "more general thing"? The only assumption is that both are algebraic closures of the same field, and it is the same assumption you make.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you're familiar with the notion of a splitting field of a polynomial $f \in F[X]$ over a field $F$.  Basically, it means you construct a "smallest possible field" $L$ containing $F$ so that all the roots of $f$ are in $L$.

It is not difficult to prove that any two splitting fields of $f$ over $F$ are $F$-isomorphic.  If $L'$ is another splitting field of $f$ over $L$, and $a_1, ... , a_n$ (resp. $a_1', ... , a_n'$) are all the roots of $f$ in $L$ (resp. $L'$), it will be possible to construct a bijection of sets $\phi: \{a_1, ... , a_n\} \rightarrow \{a_1', ... , a_n'\}$ which extends to an $F$-isomorphism of fields $L \rightarrow L'$.

What is an algebraic closure of $F$?  It is basically a splitting field over $F$ over *all* polynomials in $F[X]$.  It is the smallest possible field which contains $F$ and all the roots of all polynomials  in $F[X]$.  Given two algebraic closures $\overline{F}$ and $\overline{F}'$ of $F$, and any finite collection of polynomials $f_1, ... , f_r \in F[X]$ with roots $a_1, ... , a_n$ in $\overline{F}$ and $a_1', ... , a_n' \in \overline{F}'$, the above procedure allows you to construct an $F$-isomorphism

$$F(a_1, ... , a_n) \rightarrow F(a_1', ... , a_n').$$

You should be able to use a Zorn's lemma argument to extend such an isomorphism over *all* roots of *all* polynomials to become an isomorphism $\overline{F} \rightarrow \overline{F}'$.

Answer (score 2):

One cute way of proving this is with a [back and forth argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method). This is a very flexible technique which will serve you well for proving other "unique up to isomorphism" claims as well, provided your objects are suitably "homogenous" (whatever that means).

Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be algebraic closures of $F$.
The idea, roughly, is to define an $F$-homomorphism $\varphi : K_1 \to K_2$.
In the process of building it, we'll ensure that it's actually an isomorphism
(by moving back and forth between $K_1$ and $K_2$. This is where the name comes from).

I'll only prove this in the case that $F$ is countable (this ensures $K_1$ and $K_2$ are countable). The theorem is, of course, true for uncountable fields, but this technique becomes (only slightly) more complicated. If you're familiar with [transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction) it should be fairly clear how to extend this proof to work for all fields. If you aren't, then trust that there's an analogous proof where we "induct" on uncountable sets.

Since $K_1$ and $K_2$ are countable, enumerate them as

$$K_1 = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots\} \quad K_2 = \{b_1, b_2, b_3, \ldots\}$$

Now, how are we going to build up an isomorphism? We'll just say what needs to happen to each $a_n$ (this is moving "forth") to define $\varphi$. Of course, we'll *also* need to ensure that every $b_n$ is in the image (this is moving "back"). Let's now recursively define $\varphi$ following these ideas:

First, define $\varphi_0 : F \to F$ to be the identity map.

Now look at $a_1$. Let $p$ be its minimal polynomial over $F$ (which exists since $K_1$ is an algebraic extension of $F$). Fix a root of $p$ in
$K_2$ (which exists since $K_2$ is algebraically closed), call it $a_1'$. We can now extend $\varphi_0$ to an isomorphism $\varphi_1 : F[a_1] \to F[a_1']$. We've successfully moved "forth".

Now look at $b_1$. Again, let $p$ be its minimal polynomial, but now we work over $F[a_1']$.
Since $K_1$ is algebraically closed, we can find a root $b_1'$ in $K_1$, and now we can extend $\varphi_1$ to an isomorphism $\varphi_2 : F[a_1, b_1'] \to F[a_1', b_1]$. So we've moved "back".

We keep doing this. On odd steps, we move "forth" and extend our isomorphism from

$$F[a_1, b_1', a_2, b_2', \ldots, b_k'] \to F[a_1', b_1, a_2', b_2, \ldots, b_k]$$

to an isomorphism

$$F[a_1, b_1', a_2, b_2', \ldots, b_k', a_{k+1}] \to F[a_1', b_1, a_2', b_2, \ldots, b_k, a_{k+1}'].$$

On even steps, we move "back" and extend our isomorphism from

$$F[a_1, b_1', a_2, b_2', \ldots, b_k', a_{k+1}] \to F[a_1', b_1, a_2', b_2, \ldots, b_k, a_{k+1}'].$$

to

$$F[a_1, b_1', a_2, b_2', \ldots, b_k', a_{k+1}, b_{k+1}'] \to F[a_1', b_1, a_2', b_2, \ldots, b_k, a_{k+1}', b_{k+1}].$$

Now, what will we have done at the end of time? We have a sequence of functions $\varphi_n$, each extending the previous one to be defined on a larger subfield of $K_1$.

By the "forth" steps, we know that eventually we know what to do with every $a \in K_1$. Indeed, if $a = a_k$, then at $\varphi_{2k-1}$ we know where $a_k$ should get mapped.

Conversely, by the "back" steps, we know that every $b \in K_2$ is in the image of these maps. Indeed, if $b = b_k$, then it's the image of something under $\varphi_{2k}$.

Now we glue all these maps together (either by taking a union or a colimit, depending on your disposition) to get a map $\varphi_\omega$. The "forth" steps show that $\varphi_\omega$ is defined on all of $K_1$. The "back" steps show that its image is all of $K_2$. Thus we see $\varphi_\omega : K_1 \to K_2$ is an isomorphism, as desired. Moreover, since $\varphi_0$ was defined as the identity on $F$, it's an $F$-isomorphism.

---

I hope this helps ^_^